# Why is this character 口 causing my scanner to fail?

Tags: java, character-encoding

I'm using the Java `Scanner`.

I have a `.txt` file with this text saved in it.

```
PriceDB = {
    ["profileKeys"] = {
        ["Name - 回音山"] = "Name - 回音山",
    },
    ["char"] = {
        ["Name - 回音山"] = {
            ["CurrentValue"] = "一口价：|cffffffff70,197|TInterface\\MoneyFrame\\UI-GoldIcon:0:0:2:0|t|r",
        },
    },
}
```

All I am trying to do is open this file with a scanner and extract the `"CurrentValue"` of `70,197` from the file and save it as an int. However, every time the file is opened it will not read a line and throws a `NoSuchElementException` with `"No line found"` as the message. After fiddling around with the file and removing some of the Chinese characters one by one I narrowed it down to this little guy 口. For some reason, scanner does not like that character. I was just wondering if there's some encoding setting that I need to change or if I'm going to have use BufferedReader or  what...I'm honestly not really sure what's going on except I guess there's an encoding error. So what's happening here?

Edit: Here's the initialization of my scanner.

```
Scanner scanner;
if (region.equals("US")) {
                scanner = new Scanner(new File("C:\\Program Files\\World of Warcraft\\WTF\\Account\\313023286#1\\SavedVariables\\WoWTokenPrice.lua"));
            } else if (region.equals("EU")) {
                scanner = new Scanner(new File("C:\\Program Files\\World of Warcraft\\WTF\\Account\\313495228#1\\SavedVariables\\WoWTokenPrice.lua"));
            } else if (region.equals("China")) {
                File file = new File("C:\\Program Files\\World of Warcraft\\WTF\\Account\\232241227#1\\SavedVariables\\WoWTokenPrice.lua");
                System.out.println(file.exists());
                scanner = new Scanner(file);
            } else {
                System.exit(1);
                break;
            }
```

I just copied it as is. region == "China"

Comment: Go an example of your scanner? I'm interested in if the character encoding is set appropriately.

Comment: Are you setting the proper encoding? What encoding is that? And what is the Unicode code point for the "troublesome character"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must specify the correct encoding when creating your [Scanner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html). The constructor:

```
public Scanner(InputStream source, String charsetName)
```

> Constructs a new Scanner that produces values scanned from the specified input stream. Bytes from the stream are converted into characters using the specified charset.

[Find here your charset](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/charset/Charset.html), i guess [`UTF-16`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/charset/StandardCharsets.html#UTF_16) but not an expert in foreign characters :).

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(is, StandardCharsets.UTF-16.toString());
```

Comment: I should also note that this file will have characters from English, Korea, and Taiwan as well (don't know the languages there). Will UTF-16 support all these you think?

Comment: UTF-16 encode Unicode codepoints, therefore it can obviously store any languages' characters in Unicode standard, which covers most of the languages nowadays. [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html)

Comment: UTF-8 is working. UTF-16 prints all `???` in the console when I try and print the line. Also, your answer should be StandardCharsets.UTF-16.toString() because StrandardCharsets.UTF-16 is a charset and the constructor takes a string. So for your answer (at least what worked for me) it should be 

`Scanner scanner = new Scanner(is, StandardCharsets.UTF-8.toString());` It looks to be working for Chinese characters at least. I'll be testing it soon on the other regions. I'll give that article a look too Lưu Vĩnh Phúc thanks.

Comment: thanks for the catch, updated!! I wrote "UTF.16" but was ugly and I wanted to use a constant! ;)

Comment: Hi @user3435638 as this is your first question, if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Comment: I was kinda hesitant just because I used UTF-8 so I didn't want to mislead anyone. I accepted though because it says to pick the correct encoding which implies that UTF-16 may not work.